# Why is no return type specified in this function clearly returns?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

I am seeing this in a piece of sample code:

```
operator Vector2<float>() const    {       
  return Vector2<float>(x, y);    }
```

My 2 questions about this:

1) The function clearly returns, but there's no return type specified?

2) It's not clear exactly what is getting overloaded here, which operator.

Comment: See at the end of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421719#4421719)

Comment: `Vector2<float> operator Vector2<float>() const` would be kind of redundant, wouldn't it? :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a conversion operator, and the return type is `Vector2<float>`.